# Reading backscatter value of each pixel of Sentinel-1A images in Java?

Tags: raster, javascript, java

I am new to working with Sentinel-1A images but have better knowledge of Java. I want to get backscatter value of each pixel of Sentinel-1A image, store it and then get the frequency of each value. Can you please tell how to get it and which data structure or any database should I use to store backscatter values? Please tell the whole process. Please also tell which software I have to use for it?